# 3D Touch UICollectionView insideUITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, 3dtouch

I tried to implement 3D touch in a `tableview` that has a reusable cell with a `collectionview`. The problem is that I cannot really make it to focus on the correct cell of collection view in the cell. Here is a my code:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DiscoveryComponent else { return nil }
    let collectionView = cell.collectionView
    print("---- CollectionView \(collectionView)----")
    let collectionPoint = collectionView.convert(location, from: tableView)
    guard let collectionIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: collectionPoint) else { return nil }
    guard let collectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: collectionIndexPath) as? DiscoveryProductCell else { return nil }
    print(collectionIndexPath)
    print("Collection Cell \(collectionViewCell.productImageView.frame)")

    previewingContext.sourceRect = collectionViewCell.productImageView.frame

    return UIViewController()
}
```

The problem is when I try to apply 3D touch on the second row of `tableview` then the first cell of the collection view in the previous row of `tableview` is focusing. I think my approach is wrong.

Of course at the end I don't return yet the proper controller, because this is still in testing phase.

Answer (score 0):

registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: self.collectionView)